# invalid login id or password alert

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to java. Here I am making my first web project, i have login.jsp and servlet(doPost) for authentication and then redirects to userhome if authenticated. But if not authenticated then a message is going like:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?msg=Invalid user id and password");
```

But this message is being displayed in browser header like :

```
login.jsp?msg=Invalid user id and password
```

which i do not want. In browser no message should be displayed and should only display the url of login page(login.jsp) when user is not authenticated that is:

```
login.jsp
```

Any help?

Comment: Try to learn and use jQuery. You may request Servlet and servlet will return message/status flag to the ajax routine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: try this code. use session object.

```
session.setAttribute("error","Invalid user id and password")
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

in login.jsp use this code

```
session.getAttribute("error");
```

Comment: AFAIK the attribute in request can only be accessed by passing the request object through the dispatcher method and not after redirect.

Comment: just realized that i was using request rather than session.

Comment: it is not working, well i need to display invalid username and password in the login page but not in the browser header. Any help from somebody?

Comment: but i am facing one prob here that when i click login.jsp then that invalid userid and password is not going from that login page even after refreshing. That message displaying in page should be removed when i am clicking login.jsp or refreshing login page. Any help

Comment: you should remove the attribute after displaying it. session.removeAttribute("error");

Comment: also make sure to check for null values when reading values from session.